# Can a swipe event fire before the user raises his or her finger?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, swipe

I am using swipes to navigate through the pages of my **jQuery mobile / PhoneGap** application. Do you know if it is possible to let the page transition start after the swipe distance of (for example) 50 px? In other words: It should start *before* the finger stops touching the screen.

That would advance the user experience as they don't have this little waiting time between *raising their finger* and the *actual page transition*.

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be capable using the 'touchStart' and 'touchMove' events.  Record the position of the touch when 'touchStart' fires and then check the displacement whenever 'touchMove' fires.  If the displacement exceeds 50 px, call your page switching function.  'touchEnd' will be fired when the user lifts their finger, so you may need to compensate for that if any special actions occur then.

A good place to start is Padilicious's swipe library (http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/).  This can easily be modified to support a swipe-distance setup.

Let me know if you need anymore information.